# How can i dynamically load data into my app from the web?

Tags: android

I am planning on a "A word a day" app in android.The app will display atleast one new word everyday.I need to know how i can load data dynamically in my app.And where can i store my data in the web(preferably a free sql database) for free.

Comment: wrong place to ask :) you have try first and post the wherever you stuck or whatever the error you got.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DavidJhons But my problem is i don't know what to try.If i could just know which class i should know to load the data dynamically and where to store the data in the web that would be a great starting point for me.From there i will try and learn

Comment: from where do you expect to get the data ? which api/web service ?

Comment: I am going to enter the data myself into the db.I want the app to reflect the update that is been made in the db(i.e it should show the new word entered into the db)

Comment: So do you have a DB and API that can transmit data now ?

Comment: Actually i asked this question to know the requirements i should take care of before going on with the app.So i don't have the API or the DB now.Let me just rephrase my question."How do they do "A word a day" apps? What components(i.e,DB,web apis and the sorts),classes(Java classes that i should know about)" @DavidJhons sorry for being so naive.I really appreciate your responses.Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to omit the "Free" concept as your requirement is not straight forward, So you need to have ,

1. Data base - (in order to save your data and retrieve)
2. Web Application - to create an API in order to send data once requested
3. Web server - in order to host your web application
4. Android application - in order to call the API and get data .

As this is limit to one word, as a alternative you can use [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

1. Data base - - (in order to save your data and retrieve)
2. Web Application registered with GCM - in order to register your client app and send notifications
3. Web server - in order to host your web application
4. Android application registered with GCM